# Until i hit Start Debugging in Visual Studio Code everything is fine

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

[image]

Application works fine until start debugging!

why i encounter this error?

i also have launch.json file , what should i consider to change as i changed the port no many times from 3000 , 4000 etc but still not able to debug

[image]

Following is my code:

```
  `const http = require('http');

  const fs = require('fs');

  const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const url = req.url;
  const method = req.method;
  if (url === '/') {
    res.write('<html>');
    res.write('<head><title>Enter Message</title><head>');
    res.write('<body><form action="/message" method="POST"><input 
    type="text" name="message"><button type="submit">Send</button></form> 
    </body>');
    res.write('</html>');
    return res.end();
  }
  if (url === '/message' && method === 'POST') {
    const body = [];
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(chunk);
      body.push(chunk);
      console.log(body);
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
      const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
      console.log(parsedBody);
      const message = parsedBody.split('=')[1];
      console.log(message);
      fs.writeFileSync('message.txt', message);
    });
    res.statusCode = 302;
    res.setHeader('Location', '/');
    return res.end();
  }
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.write('<html>');
  res.write('<head><title>My First Page</title><head>');
  res.write('<body><h1>Hello from my Node.js Server!</h1></body>');
  res.write('</html>');
  res.end();
});

server.listen(4000);
`
```

Comment: Another process is already using port 4000. Make sure you don't have multiple copies of your app running.

Comment: @AKX i tried no instances were open i also tried to search with "tasklist" could not find there also